# Use NetTopologySuite to offset a polyline with variable distance

Tags: nettopologysuite

NetTopologySuite seems able to [create a buffer polygon](https://nettopologysuite.github.io/NetTopologySuite/api/NetTopologySuite.Operation.Buffer.VariableBuffer.html#NetTopologySuite_Operation_Buffer_VariableBuffer__ctor_NetTopologySuite_Geometries_Geometry_System_Double___) with a varying buffer distance at each vertex along a line. But what about just offsetting a polyline with variable distance? Is there anyway to use built-in functions, or manipulate the built-in functions to achieve what I want?

In other words, can it do what [CavalierContours](https://github.com/jbuckmccready/CavalierContours) is doing, plus it should be able to handle the variable offsets at the points on the polyline?

Comment: No, it can't do what CavalierContours is doing